# Python BeautifulSoup Mirror

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, translation

There is a website that has two sites with different languages. When I looked at them, the websites follow exactly the same html structure however, the only difference is the links value which is contained in the tags (english points to english, chinese point to chinese in this case). I am wondering is there a handy way in BeautifulSoup so that I could loop through all the leaf nodes that contain text and make a lookup table for the translation.

the code might be something look like this:

```
www.foo.com/cn/bar/lang=en
<div href="ww.foo.com/cn/bar1/lang=en"><b>This is awesome</b><b>bye<br>bye</b></div>


www.foo.com/cn/bar/lang=cn
<div href="ww.foo.com/cn/bar1/lang=cn"><b>棒极了</b><b>拜<br>拜</b></div>
```

the output that I want is something like this:

{'This is awesome': '棒极了' , 'bye': '拜'} (translation is not that perfect :)

They don't have to be in the form of dictionary but I think that would be the best type to store this kind of information.

Here are a few thoughts that I have and not sure there would be a better way. 
1. Find element leaf element that contains text for English, find selector or something to locate this element uniquely and then in the Chinese website, use the selector(excluding the different href) to locate the corresponding element and then find the Chinese translation.

1. There might be a method somewhere that I don't know, I assume it look like this. 
   BeautifulSoup(src).findAllLeaves(text!='') to get a list of all the leave node which contains text. Then do the same thing for the Chinese website, which should contain the same elements as the English. Then build a lookup dict based on those two lists.
2. Or use prettify() to list the HTML tree in a well formatted way, then loop through every single row to find the corresponding Chinese.

Let me know if I have described my question clear enough and any idea of how to implement this would be helpful.  Efficient shell command(grep, sed, awk) or even other languages are also welcome.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You might want to look up `mytag.children` which returns a generator that lets you iterate over all children, `mytag.content` which returns a list of all children inclusive non-tags or `mytag.descendants`. With that you could traverse both trees simultaneously, calling `mytag.string` or `mytag.stripped_strings` on each node. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 0):

For the html file structure you have given,

```
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
>>> soup.findAll('b') 
[<b>This is awesome</b>, <b>bye<br />bye</b>]
```

Maybe, several findAll sentences are needed to extract text in different tags, such as `<p>`,`<strong>`.
Hope it will help.

Comment: I am so sorry that the example I gave is so limited to represent a real-world page. Even I am not sure whether all texts are included in some specific groups of tags. But still thanks for your advice and I will give it a try and see if all the texts could be group by a few tags.